# How to propagate update in belongstomany relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel-4, relationship

I have two models Shelf, Book and Quote

```
class Shelf extends Eloquent {
    public function quotes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Book');
    }
}

class Book extends Eloquent {
    protected $touches = array('shelfs');
    public function quotes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Quote');
    }

    public function shelfs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Shelf');
    }
}

class Quote extends Eloquent {
    protected $touches = array('books');

    public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Book')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

when I update Qoute model, updated_at in Qout model table is updated, but Shelf model is not.

Am I doing something wrong?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In earlier version,you can just update only one level relation that is declared in `$touch` array within its own model, not from parent model yet. You need to update to above [v4.2.9](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.2.9/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1563) to get this feature because it is not included till [v4.2.8](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.2.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1527). To be more safe, try to use starting from [v4.2.10](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.2.10/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1563) which is included checking relation is null or not.

**Edit**

Need to upgrade to [v5](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1619) to get this as @Dusan Plavak mentioned in comment.

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: Hmm thanks, but actually in v4.2.10 it is not fixed. Well sadly it is not fixed even in v4.2.17. But it is fixed in [v5](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1619) and they do not make backporting... If you will edit your answer I will accept it anyway because it point me right way to discover that